# problem using "promise.all" in a loop of image carousel

Tags: javascript, css, promise, es6-promise

the 2 promises are:

1. loading the next image `Load_Img_p`.
2. a waiting animation before moving to the next image `Timing_Anim_p`.

It also has a visual animation encouraging you to wait while waiting for the next image to fully load `Hourglass_f`.

the idea is this:
execute in parallel `Timing_Anim_p` and `Load_Img_p`.

in the case of `Timing_Anim_p` before `Load_Img_p` is resolved, show `Wait_Img_Load`
this is done by a simple flag named `imgOnLoad`

code for `Load_Img_p`

```
var imgOnLoad = false;

const Load_Img_p = (imgScr ) => new Promise( (resolve ) => 
  {
  imgOnLoad   = true;
  const img   = new Image();
  img.onload  =()=>{ imgOnLoad = false; resolve( img )  };
  img.onerror =()=>{ imgOnLoad = false; resolve( null ) }; 
  img.src     = imgScr;
  })
```

in situ code test for `Hourglass_f` and `Timing_Anim_p`

```js
var imgOnLoad = true;  // need also this one to reject other user commands on interface. 

const
  hourglass_elm = document.querySelector('#hourglass')
, Hourglass_f   = (run=false) =>
    {
    hourglass_elm.classList.toggle('showHourglass', run);
    }
, Timing_Anim_e = document.querySelector('#Timing-Anim-bar')
, Timing_Anim_p =()=> new Promise( (resolve ) =>
    {
    Timing_Anim_e.addEventListener('transitionend', ()=>
      {
      Timing_Anim_e.classList.remove('showTiming');
      Hourglass_f(imgOnLoad);
      resolve('Timing_Anim_p ended ok');
      }
      , { once: true }
      );
    Timing_Anim_e.classList.add('showTiming');
    })
    ;

btn_test_A.onclick =_=> Hourglass_f(true);
btn_test_B.onclick =_=> Hourglass_f(false);
btn_test_C.onclick =_=> Timing_Anim_p();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #03063a;
  }
#hourglass {
  visibility        : hidden;
  width             : 100px;
  height            : 100px;
  stroke            : #ff146e;
  stroke-dasharray  : 80;
  stroke-dashoffset : 200;
  }
#hourglass.showHourglass {
  visibility : visible;
  animation  : hourglassAnim 1400ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
@keyframes hourglassAnim { to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; } }

#Timing-Anim-bar {
  width    : 500px;
  height   : 10px;
  border   : 1px #9acd32 solid;
  position : relative;
  }
#Timing-Anim-bar::before {
  position   : absolute;
  display    : block;
  top        : 0;
  left       : 0;
  height     : 100%;
  width      : 0%;
  content    : '';  
  background : #0cfa2c;
  }
#Timing-Anim-bar.showTiming::before {
  transition : width 3s linear;
  width      : 100%;
  }
```

```html
<svg id="hourglass" viewbox="0 0 200 200" class="" >
  <circle id="c5" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
<div id="Timing-Anim-bar"></div>

<br><br>
<button id="btn_test_A">hourglass true</button>
<button id="btn_test_B">hourglass false</button>
<button id="btn_test_C">test Timing_Anim_p</button>
```

complete image change loop code, **but** without using promise.ALL:

```js
const 
  img_box = document.querySelector('#img-box')
, imgs_src_list =
    [ 'https://picsum.photos/id/124/400/300.webp'
    , 'https://picsum.photos/id/146/400/300.webp'
    , 'https://picsum.photos/id/155/400/300.webp'
    , 'https://picsum.photos/id/219/400/300.webp'
    ];
var 
  imgOnLoad = false
, img_index = 0;
  ;
const
  hourglass_elm = document.querySelector('#hourglass')
, Hourglass_f   = (run=false) =>
    {
    hourglass_elm.classList.toggle('showHourglass', run);
    }
, Timing_Anim_e = document.querySelector('#Timing-Anim-bar')
, Timing_Anim_p =()=> new Promise( (resolve ) =>
    {
    Timing_Anim_e.addEventListener('transitionend', ()=>
      {
      Timing_Anim_e.classList.remove('showTiming');
      Hourglass_f(imgOnLoad);
      resolve('Timing_Anim_p ended ok');
      }
      , { once: true }
      );
    Timing_Anim_e.classList.add('showTiming');
    })
, Load_Img_p = (imgScr ) => new Promise( (resolve ) => 
    {
    imgOnLoad   = true;
    const img   = new Image();
    img.onload  =()=>{ imgOnLoad = false; resolve( img )  };
    img.onerror =()=>{ imgOnLoad = false; resolve( null ) }; 
    img.src     = imgScr;
    })
, chkBxPlayer = document.querySelector('#chkBx-player')
  ;
chkBxPlayer.addEventListener('change',()=>
  {
  if (chkBxPlayer.checked)
    {
    carousel_Loop();
    }
  else
    {
    Hourglass_f(false);
    Timing_Anim_e.classList.remove('showTiming');
    }
  })
async function carousel_Loop()
  {
  let nxt_src, nxt_imgIdx = img_index
    ;
  while (chkBxPlayer.checked)  
    {
    nxt_imgIdx = ++nxt_imgIdx % imgs_src_list.length;
    nxt_src    = imgs_src_list[nxt_imgIdx];

    await Timing_Anim_p();
    if (!chkBxPlayer.checked) break;

    Hourglass_f(true);
    
    let newImg = await Load_Img_p( nxt_src );

    Hourglass_f(false);

    if (!chkBxPlayer.checked) break;
    if (newImg===null)
      {
      chkBxPlayer.checked = false;
      console.log('Image loading error', nxt_src );
      break;
      }
    img_index = nxt_imgIdx;
    img_box.replaceChildren( newImg );
    }
  Hourglass_f(false); // some security...
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #03063a;
  }
#img-box, label {
  margin        : 20px;
  border        : 1px whitesmoke solid;
  padding       : 10px;
  width         : fit-content;
  height        : fit-content;
  background    : lightgrey;
  border-radius : 5px;
  position      : relative
  }
#hourglass {
  position    : absolute;
  top         : 50px;
  left        : 50px;
  visibility        : hidden;
  width             : 100px;
  height            : 100px;
  stroke            : #ff146e;
  stroke-dasharray  : 80;
  stroke-dashoffset : 200;
  }
#hourglass.showHourglass {
  visibility : visible;
  animation  : hourglassAnim 1400ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
@keyframes hourglassAnim { to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; } }

#Timing-Anim-bar {
  width    : 500px;
  height   : 10px;
  border   : 1px #9acd32 solid;
  position : relative;
  }
#Timing-Anim-bar::before {
  position   : absolute;
  display    : block;
  top        : 0;
  left       : 0;
  height     : 100%;
  width      : 0%;
  content    : '';  
  background : #0cfa2c;
  }
#Timing-Anim-bar.showTiming::before {
  transition : width 3s linear;
  width      : 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="img-box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/124/400/300.webp" alt="">
  <svg id="hourglass" viewbox="0 0 220 220" class="">
    <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="50" stroke-width="10" fill="transparent" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="Timing-Anim-bar"></div>
<br>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="chkBx-player" > play diaporama </label>
```

What I tried, but the loop stops at the first change...
What's wrong?

[edit] adding `smallDelay()` as suggested by **Terance Edmonds**, which solved a part of this problem, because there is an overlap between the placement of the image and the start of the next loop. but this is more of a patch than a solution.

```js
const 
  img_box = document.querySelector('#img-box')
, imgs_src_list =
    [ 'https://picsum.photos/id/124/400/300.webp'
    , 'https://picsum.photos/id/146/400/300.webp'
    , 'https://picsum.photos/id/155/400/300.webp'
    , 'https://picsum.photos/id/219/400/300.webp'
    ];
var 
  imgOnLoad = false
, img_index = 0;
  ;
const
  smallDelay    =_=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,200))
, hourglass_elm = document.querySelector('#hourglass')
, Hourglass_f   = (run=false) =>
    {
    hourglass_elm.classList.toggle('showHourglass', run);
    }
, Timing_Anim_e = document.querySelector('#Timing-Anim-bar')
, Timing_Anim_p =()=> new Promise( (resolve ) =>
    {
    Timing_Anim_e.addEventListener('transitionend', ()=>
      {
      Timing_Anim_e.classList.remove('showTiming');
      Hourglass_f(imgOnLoad);
      resolve('Timing_Anim_p ended ok');
      }
      , { once: true }
      );
    Timing_Anim_e.classList.add('showTiming');
    })
, Load_Img_p = (imgScr ) => new Promise( (resolve ) => 
    {
    imgOnLoad   = true;
    const img   = new Image();
    img.onload  =()=>{ imgOnLoad = false; resolve( img )  };
    img.onerror =()=>{ imgOnLoad = false; resolve( null ) }; 
    img.src     = imgScr;
    })
, chkBxPlayer = document.querySelector('#chkBx-player')
  ;
chkBxPlayer.addEventListener('change',()=>
  {
  if (chkBxPlayer.checked)
    {
    carousel_Loop();
    }
  else
    {
    Hourglass_f(false);
    Timing_Anim_e.classList.remove('showTiming');
    }
  })
async function carousel_Loop()
  {
  let nxt_src, nxt_imgIdx = img_index
    ;
  while (chkBxPlayer.checked)  
    {
    nxt_imgIdx = ++nxt_imgIdx % imgs_src_list.length;
    nxt_src    = imgs_src_list[nxt_imgIdx];

    let resp = await Promise.all([ Timing_Anim_p() , Load_Img_p( nxt_src ) ]);

    Hourglass_f(false);

    let newImg = resp[1];

    if (!chkBxPlayer.checked) break;
 
    if (newImg===null)
      {
      chkBxPlayer.checked = false;
      console.log('Image loading error', nxt_src );
      break;
      }
    img_index = nxt_imgIdx;
    img_box.replaceChildren( newImg );
    await smallDelay();       //--- --- --- patch
    }
  Hourglass_f(false); // some security...
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #03063a;
  }
#img-box, label {
  margin        : 20px;
  border        : 1px whitesmoke solid;
  padding       : 10px;
  width         : fit-content;
  height        : fit-content;
  background    : lightgrey;
  border-radius : 5px;
  position      : relative
  }
#hourglass {
  position    : absolute;
  top         : 50px;
  left        : 50px;
  visibility        : hidden;
  width             : 100px;
  height            : 100px;
  stroke            : #ff146e;
  stroke-dasharray  : 80;
  stroke-dashoffset : 200;
  }
#hourglass.showHourglass {
  visibility : visible;
  animation  : hourglassAnim 1400ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
@keyframes hourglassAnim { to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; } }

#Timing-Anim-bar {
  width    : 500px;
  height   : 10px;
  border   : 1px #9acd32 solid;
  position : relative;
  }
#Timing-Anim-bar::before {
  position   : absolute;
  display    : block;
  top        : 0;
  left       : 0;
  height     : 100%;
  width      : 0%;
  content    : '';  
  background : #0cfa2c;
  }
#Timing-Anim-bar.showTiming::before {
  transition : width 3s linear;
  width      : 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="img-box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/124/400/300.webp" alt="">

  <svg id="hourglass" viewbox="0 0 220 220" class="" >
    <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="50" stroke-width="10" fill="transparent" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="Timing-Anim-bar"></div>
<br>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="chkBx-player" > play diaporama </label>
```

Comment: I doubt that all that CSS is necessary for a [mre] – but look at [`HTMLImageElement.decode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) for a correct way to get an image-load promise (yours has global state and a race condition).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with the below code, that when the promises are executed, the 'showTiming' is executed just after the transition is ended so the animation won't start over which leads only to one image being loaded.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  Timing_Anim_e.classList.add('showTiming')
}, 0);
```

Comment: well seen! but I simply added a delay at the end of the loop, to counter this overlap. But I'm not sure if this is the best thing to do, I'm still looking into using the decode() method...